# Navigation highlights as you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I'm creating a portfolio website: https://invis.io/GNGW7QN5DA8#/291319917_Desktop

It's one long page page where you scroll through one project, one after the other.

**My problem:** I want the navigation to highlight blue as you scroll onto each project (and go back to grey as you scroll past).
Please see this 14 second explanation video: https://vimeo.com/264827483

**Additional question:** Since the page size will be very big with lots of content, I want the projects to be hidden until you scroll... this is what I've been using so far:

```js
function yHandler() {
  var allcontent = document.getElementById('allcontent');
  var contentHeight = allcontent.offsetHeight - 500;
  var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
  var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
  if (y >= contentHeight) {
    allcontent.innerHTML += '<div>NEWLY INSERTED CONTENT</div>'
    // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
  }
}

window.onscroll = yHandler;
```

Can I achieve the navigation highlight alongside the content being hidden until scroll with that JS?

Thank you so much for your time!